# How can I deploy an angular-spring-postgres application on gcp?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm new to GCP and currently, I try to deploy all my applications on their services.

For an application in a single container I use CloudRun which I already really like.

Now I want to deploy an application that uses Angular in the frontend and spring in the backend and a SQL-DB (Postgres). Every part of this is in its own separated container.

Should I use for this purpose although CloudRun or does GCP have more suitable services I should consider to use if I want to host a scalable and serverless Application? So is there such a thing as the best practice for Frontend-backend architecture applications on GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use these services:

- [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart) to host the database. It's managed for you and efficient
- Cloud Run for the business tier (the spring application).

Be careful, with spring the cold start can take several seconds. I wrote [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c) (the article is quite old and the perf are now better on Cloud Run, but the latency on the first request exists (and take 5 - 7s for an hello world container)). Add several CPU (4 is a good number) to speed up the cold start or use the --min-instance parameter for this (or other solution that you can find in [one of my articles](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894))

- For the front end, I recommend you to host the static files on Cloud Storage.
- To serve this on internet, put a Load Balancer in front of this

  - Create a [serverless network endpoint group (NEG) for Cloud Run service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)
  - Create a [Cloud Storage backend to serve the static files.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets)
  - Use the domain that you want and serve it in SSL
  - *Optionally, use CDN to cache your static files.*

Answer (score 0):

CloudRun runs stateless containers. It doesn't make a distinction between frontend and backend, or worker jobs.

You can run your frontend, backend, admin code base as Cloud Run service.
Next to these you setup Cloud SQL for your operational database, and connect the Cloud Run services with the Cloud SQL connector so they are able to use for read/write queries.